# Monitor position not staying put on Windows 10 Anniversary edition

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-10-v1607

I have 4 monitors, 3 1080P's and a 1366x768.

Just updated to Windows 10 Anniversary edition, now under display settings, whenever I move the 1336 to where it's supposed to be, it works for a couple of seconds and then snaps back.

I have had this setup since Windows 8, and always update to a new Windows OS as soon as it comes out, and have never had issues.

[image: Monitor position not persisting]

To clarify, the monitor works at the position I set it to for a couple of seconds (**1** is to the left of **3**) and then it snaps back to **1** being underneath **3**.

Whilst 1 == 3, I can drag Windows to the left to move to that monitor, once it snaps back, I need to drag down again to move to that monitor.

It feels very similar to the 15 second confirmation dialogue you would get on earlier versions of Windows, but nothing of the sort appears.

If I disable the 1366 monitor, then I can position the three 1080p's however I like and everything persists, but when it's enabled I start getting issues.

Any ideas?

Comment: I assume you *did* click `Apply` after rearranging. Does it persist any better if you `F5` refresh the desktop within those few seconds?

Comment: @dxiv I click apply, and no other dialogue boxes or notifications appear

Comment: @dxiv Refreshing the desktop doesn't change anything, I think it's a bug in this version of Windows